# Using StringBuilder to concat query string

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to make some query string in java

here is my code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int maxDay = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
for(int co=0; co<=maxDay; co++) {
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     sb.append(ft.format(c.getTime())).append("','");
     incDate = sb.toString();
}
```

output now : 20190712','20190713','20190714','20190715','
In some case I need to make it something like this: '20190712','20190713','20190714','20190715'

Comment: Please explain what you want to accomplish. There is no way we can deduce what you are aiming for

Comment: @roookeee from **20190712','20190713','20190714','20190715','** to **'20190712','20190713','20190714','20190715'**

Comment: You can use String.join() to concatenate lists with delimiters: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-join-examples/, it would be better than making it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the StringBuilder with a single quote and after the loop has finished, remove the last 2 chars which you don't want:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("'");
int maxDay = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
for(int co=0; co <= maxDay; co++) {
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    sb.append(ft.format(c.getTime())).append("','");
}
if (sb.length() > 1) {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
    incDate = sb.toString();
}
```

I also moved `incDate = sb.toString();` out of the loop.